# Bash script: How to execute commands consecutively without waiting for the previous one?

Tags: bash, scripts

In a bash script that execute 2 commands like this

```
#!/bin/bash
gedit
nautilus
```

Nautilus starts not before gedit is closed? How can i avoid this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simply put `gedit` in the background

```
#!/bin/bash
gedit &
nautilus
```